# Android changing visibility GifTextView not working in AsyncTask class, why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

So in my AsyncTask class (1, 'gekozenOptochtDataParser') I execute an other `AsyncTask` class (2). in (2) I try to make a GIF visible and gone, but it doesn't work. This has something to do with the layout because when I place the '`GifTextView`' in the footer, header and 'MainActivity' it works (footer and header are different layouts), but when I try to do this in the '`MainActivity`' layout it doesn't work. Do I need to use '`RunOnThread`' statement? Or what is the problem?

Code for making '`GifTextView`' visible and gone (2):

```
public class removeDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
Context c;
//ProgressDialog asyncDialog;
String page;
boolean running;
GifTextView loadingGif;

public removeDialog(GifTextView loadingGif, String page, Context c) {
    this.loadingGif = loadingGif;
    this.page = page;
    this.c = c;

    //asyncDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    loadingGif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if (page == "algemeneVoorwaarden") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(c, algemeneVoorwaarden.class);
        c.startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (page == "contact") {
        Intent intent = new Intent(c, contactTest.class);
        c.startActivity(intent);
    }

    super.onPreExecute();
    running = true;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    int i = 2;
    while(running){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(i-- == 0){
            running = false;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    //hide the dialog
    loadingGif.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

Code where I execute the class (1, 'gekozenOptochtDataParser'):

```
  //footer en header toevoegen
  View header = View.inflate(c, R.layout.headergekozenoptocht, null);
  View footer = View.inflate(c, R.layout.footer, null);
  View gekozenOptochtLayout = View.inflate(c, R.layout.activity_gekozen_optocht, null);

        //gif image view pakken
        final GifTextView loadingGif = (GifTextView) gekozenOptochtLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        voorwaarden.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new removeDialog(loadingGif, "algemeneVoorwaarden", c).execute();
            }
        });

        contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new removeDialog(loadingGif, "contact", c).execute();
            }
        });

        //header en footer toevoegen
        lv.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
        lv.addFooterView(footer, null, false);

        //adapter toevoegen
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Code in the 'MainActivity':

```
new gekozenOptochtDownloader(gekozenOptocht.this, urlAddress, lv).execute();
```

Comment: I already thought that but how can I fix this?

Comment: Nothing has helped me yet.

Comment: Post all of your code related to `gekozenOptochtDataParser`

Comment: I want the 'GifTextView' in the layout of the 'MainActivity' but I need to execute the code in the 'gekozenOptochtDataParser' script.

Comment: Mallaudin it's just some code of dataParse from MySQL database

Comment: Mike M. I got no idea of how I could add this to a view. Android is new for me.

Comment: The second AsyncTask starts only after I click on a 'TextView' in the footer.

Comment: But I execute the code in 'gekozenOptochtDataParser' so it doesn't change anything if I use 'addView()' in the 'MainActivity'.

Comment: I still don't know exactly what to do.

Comment: I fixed it myself. I just added a 'GifTextView' to the executor

Comment: You really should fix your string comparison, though. Doesn't matter if it works, it's not correct

Comment: I already did it, but why can't I use '=='?